# Стоит ли разбить на умные компоненты или все писать в одном?

Tags: reactjs, компоненты, containers

У меня есть 3 компонента - это формы (Авторизация, Регистрация, Забыли пароль), все они глупые и выводятся на 1 странице.
И пока написал 1 умный компонент, который содержит всю логику работы над этими формами.
У меня пока что получился такой код:

```
const FormsContainer = () => {
  const [forms, setForms] = useState({
    signIn: false,
    signUp: false,
    recovery: false,
  });

const [inputsValid, setInputsValid] = useState({
    signIn: {
      login: false,
      password: false,
    },
    signUp: {
      email: false,
      login: false,
      password: false,
      passwordRepeat: false,
    },
    recovery: {
      email: false,
    },
  });

  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    signIn: {
      login: '',
      password: '',
    },
    signUp: {
      email: '',
      login: '',
      password: '',
      passwordRepeat: '',
    },
    recovery: {
      email: '',
    },
  });

  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({
    signIn: {
      login: '',
      password: '',
    },
    signUp: {
      email: '',
      login: '',
      password: '',
      passwordRepeat: '',
    },
    recovery: {
      email: '',
    },
  });


    const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    switch (name) {
      case 'sign-in__login':
        setInputs({
          ...inputs,
          signIn: { ...inputs.signIn, login: value },
        });
        break;

      case 'sign-in__password':
        setInputs({
          ...inputs,
          signIn: { ...inputs.signIn, password: value },
        });
        break;

      case 'sign-up__email':
        if (value.length === 0) {
          return setErrors({
            ...errors,
            signUp: { ...errors.signUp, email: '' },
          });
        }
        if (emailValidation(value)) {
          setErrors({
            ...errors,
            signUp: { ...errors.signUp, email: '' },
          });
        }
        setInputs({
          ...inputs,
          signUp: { ...inputs.signUp, email: value },
        });
        break;

      case 'sign-up__login':
        setInputs({
          ...inputs,
          signUp: { ...inputs.signUp, login: value },
        });
        break;

      case 'sign-up__password':
        if (value.length === 0) {
          return setErrors({
            ...errors,
            signUp: { ...errors.signUp, password: '' },
          });
        }

        if (value.length >= 6 && value.length <= 32) {
          setErrors({
            ...errors,
            signUp: { ...errors.signUp, password: '' },
          });
        }
        setInputs({
          ...inputs,
          signUp: { ...inputs.signUp, password: value },
        });
        break;

      case 'sign-up__password-repeat':
        if (value.length === 0) {
          return setErrors({
            ...errors,
            signUp: { ...errors.signUp, passwordRepeat: '' },
          });
        }
        setInputs({
          ...inputs,
          signUp: { ...inputs.signUp, passwordRepeat: value },
        });
        break;

      case 'recovery__email':
        setInputs({
          ...inputs,
          recovery: { ...inputs.recovery, email: value },
        });
        break;
    }
  };
}
```

Это конечно не все функций в этом компоненте, но файл прям вырос и относительно нечитабелен.
 Такой подход нормальный или стоит разбить каждый компонент на умный, чтобы у каждой формы был свой родительский умный компонент? Я думаю так код уменьшится в разы, но отчасти один и тот же функционал, где просто продублирую. Подскажите пожалуйста как быть.

Comment: ты тут кинул сборник reducer-ов и это не логично. Лучше отделять как компоненты так и reducer-ы для этих компонентов по ихнему логическому смыслу. В конечном итоге когда ты подключишь что то для управления состоянием например redux все это так и так будет слито в одну кучу через определенный метод redux.Но как работают остальные библиотеки управления состоянием я знать не знаю по этому то что я советую касается наличия именно redux да и смысла существования компонентов